# Action<T> Get parameter value

Tags: c#

Goal: Pass an Action< T > to a method to be ran. The idea is if the method uses T then we can specify the type we will be passing into the method as a parameter rather than having to use dynamics.

Issue: I'm unable to get the parameter value, what is the best way to do this (most likely using reflection)?

Code:

```
public static void RunVoidMethod<T>(Action<T> methodToRun)
{            
    try
    {
        // Below is a ParameterInfo, I want the parameter value for methodToRun
        var parameterValue = methodToRun.Method.GetParameters()[0];    
        methodToRun(parameterValue);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }    
}
```

The worst case scenario is I can add an optional parameter which can also be of type T but I'm hoping to avoid this if possible.

Comment: The value of a parameter is an *argument*, and it is a thing that the *caller* provides. A delegate is a *callee*, not a *caller*; it tells you *what kind of thing it expects* -- the *caller* is required to provide that.

Comment: Please include what you are trying to do in the methodToRun I'm having a hard time trying to figure out wither you are thinking of it the right way

Comment: @Scarnet Nothing special, what happens in methodToRun shouldn't matter for this question. This method I'm mostly just for fun but it might have some uses in the future.

Comment: try looking at the Activator.CreateInstance() it might be what you are looking for

Comment: It's still very, very unclear what you're trying to achieve. Whether it's for fun or not, you must have *something* in mind that you're not clearly expressing at the moment. How would you expect to call this, and what would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this (I am not 100% certain since your post didn't really include a question, just a statement).

```
public static void RunVoidMethod<T>(Action<T> methodToRun, T param)
{            
    try
    {
        methodToRun(param);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }    
}
```

Comment: :P I added that just into my main post but yeah, that does work but it's something I'm trying to avoid if possible. I feel like we should be able to get the parameter from the Action somehow but I have a bad feeling you can't. I'll update my main post to be more descriptive. Thank you for posting.

Comment: Well, no because the `action` you are passing in is the function itself and not the actual call. The parameter value will not exist at that stage.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for bettering my understanding. I'll mark this as answered (in 4 minutes).

Comment: There's no reason to ever do this.  If you're just going to always ask for the parameter you're providing, you might as well just accept a parameterless method.  You're doing work for no benefit.

Comment: @Servy Maybe I've removed all of the corresponding code in this method? There is some reflection in this method to provide some very basic information which I'm hoping to use in conjunction with other logging functionality I've made. A lot of this is me just trying out things though, there isn't always a point. I also noted you removed my question, thanks for that - you make it much more enjoyable using stackoverflow...

Comment: @Zain No, I don't mean that the method isn't doing anything (it isn't, but I assume there is some actual work in there).  Rather, you shouldn't be accepting a parameter just so you can pass it into a delegate you're accepting.  Just accept a delegate of type `Action`. The only reason to accept a delegate with a parameter is because you need to provide a parameter that the caller can't provide themselves.

Comment: @Servy I do not know how to do that or how to describe that accurately enough to find how to do that on Google. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `public static void RunVoidMethod(Action methodToRun)` You just remove the parameter, and you're done.  The method has no need to provide a parameter to the method, so there's no reason to accept  a method that requires one.

Comment: @Servy Oh, I see what you mean now. Thank you, that solves my problem and will help me a lot in the future too I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the purpose of using a delegate this way, but even if you did you can always use the delegate to call the method that takes the parameter instead.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintTest(() => DelegateTest("Hello"));
    }

    public static void DelegateTest(string test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test);
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    public static void PrintTest(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception w)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, there is an article on MSDN that explains how to invoke delegates if the Type isn't known until runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-hook-up-a-delegate-using-reflection